# Meteor Framework save image to server

Tags: mongodb, file-upload, meteor, multipartform-data

I am using Meteor Framework with MongoDB in my project. I am trying to save uploaded profile images to Meteor server (under public folder). How to save profile images on Meteor without additional package ?

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I tried it with CollectionFS but wondering if it is possible without using additional collection or so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently looked in to this for a project and the conclusion is came to is that you should not upload files to the Meteor app folders at all (not sure you can do it even). Instead, use a separate storage service for static file storage. It seems like the majority of the developers out there use [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (and so do I) but there are other options, like [Rackspace Cloud Files](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/upload-files-directly-to-rackspace-cloud-files-from-the-browser/). You can use S3 for free for a year and I believe there is something similar for Cloud Files.